# How can I convert this to asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my classic asp app, I have a markup page with a bunch of checkboxes. The checkbox control ID is bscv.

Once a user checks a box and clicks submit, the value is processed on the next page called next.asp.

Based on the value of the checked box, I display the correct dropdown.

I use the following code on next.asp to display the correct dropdown.

```
If bsvc = "master" Then
    ' only master was checked
    ' "If the user checks only master checkbox, ...txtmaster with 2 options... is displayed."

%>
<select id="txtmaster" name="txtmaster">
        <option value="">-Select a service-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
<%
Elseif InStr(bsvc, "master") > 0 Then
    ' Master was checked, but something else was also checked
    ' display txtmaster with all 7 options dropdowon 1 and 2       

%>
 <select id="txtmaster" name="txtmaster">
        <option value="">-Select a service-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
     </select>
<%
Elseif Len(bsvc) > 0 Then
    ' something was checked, but not master
    ' " display only dropdown with 3 to 7 ."

%>
<select id="txtmaster" name="txtmaster">
          <option value="">-Select a service-</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="4">5</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>

<%
Else
    Response.Write "Error: You did not check any business serviced"
End If
%>
```

This works great.

Now, on asp.net, I am using multiview and I am trying to accomplish the same.

On view1, I have the checkboxes. When I click next, I will like to display the correct dropdownlist based on the value of checked box.

How can I accomplish something similar as the code above?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: A simple web search brings up lots of samples and tutorials for the `MultiView` control, we're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: WOW, what a zinger! My parents raised me to say "If you are having a bad day, don't take it out on someone else" I have already written over 1167 lines of the multiview code. I just need guidance on how to write this bit. That's all. But thanks a lot for your constructive contribution.

Comment: I PRAY for you Coding Gorilla. I pray for you.

You REAP what you SOW.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be very similar to what you have...

Use an `<asp:checkboxlist>` in your markup.

Then for your submit button's on-click event, you can set your dropdown lists' 'visible' property to true or false, based on the checked values you find in your checkboxlist.

Alternatively, you could declare some `listitem` objects, have just one `dropdownlist`, and add/remove `listitem` based on the checked values from your `checkboxlist`.

```
For each myItem as listitem in myCheckboxlist
if ctype(myItem, checkox).checked then...
```

something along that line of thought anyway

Comment: Thank you so very much Tamago for your kindness. My biggest issue is how to get the controls recognized from view1 to view2.

The multiview has 3 pages or views and while the checkboxes are on view1, the dropdownlist is on view2.

Again, thanks a lot and God Bless.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Multiview, so forgive me if I'm totally off base. But it looks like the controls on view 1 should be available directly.  Since you're using a Multiview you're never actually leaving the page, just posting back and changing the active view.  So every control on view 1 (or any other view) is still accessible.

If you can't refer to the checkboxes directly, say if the checkboxes are dynamic (like databound or something), you should be able to use View1.FindControl or something similar.

Am I missing something?

```
'View1 contains three CheckBoxes and ButtonNext.
'View2 contains three DropDownLists and ButtonBack.

Protected Sub ButtonNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNext.Click
    SetListVisibility()
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2)
End Sub

Protected Sub ButtonBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonBack.Click
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1)
End Sub

Private Sub SetListVisibility()
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        If CheckBox2.Checked Or CheckBox3.Checked Then
            DropDownList1.Visible = False
            DropDownList2.Visible = False
            DropDownList3.Visible = True
        Else
            DropDownList1.Visible = True
            DropDownList2.Visible = False
            DropDownList3.Visible = False
        End If
    Else
        DropDownList1.Visible = False
        DropDownList2.Visible = True
        DropDownList3.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance but I think you are solving a different problem.

Please allow me to explain again. I have 3 dropdowns on the markup page. Dropdown1 has 2 options, dropdown2 has 5 options, dropdown3 has 7 options ( a combination of 1 and 2). If user checks for instance INKS checkbox, only show dropdown1, if INKS is not selected, show dropdown2, if INKS and another checkbox is selected, show dropdown3. This works great in classic asp but I can't figure it out in asp.net multiview. That's the issue.

Comment: I'm still not seeing where the disconnect is. Are you having trouble figuring out how to detect the value of a checkbox? Edited my answer to make it more specific. If that isn't enough you're going to have to help us understand what you're stuck on.

Comment: I have it working now. I approached it differently. I have the values stored on the db, created 3 small subs and depending on the value of checked box, display corresponding dropdown list and it is working flawlessly now. Thanks a lot for your help and time. 

Much appreciated. Same appreciation goes to Tamago. You guys will get your rewards for your assistance and kindness.